# How to search in Active Record with the condition A + B

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to specify each condition for Maintenance and Ability associated with a Person and retrieve each of them.

Normally, the query would be to retrieve the records that contain the two conditions, Person.maintenances and Person.abilities.

```
A = Person.maintenances.where(~~~~)
B = Person.abilities.where(~~~)
```

I want to get all of the above in a single query as a Person.
(What I want = A + B in a single query)

Also, I don't want to have the N+1 problem, but I would like to know how to prevent the query from being issued because the conditions of Person.maintenances and Person.abilities are separated.

```rb
class Person << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :maintenances
  has_many :abilities
end

class Maintenance << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end

class Ability << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
end
```

※I'm using MySQL

Thanks.

Comment: where is your query ? please share table structure with sample data and query where you are faacing issues.

Comment: Small error in your code: `Person.maintenances` should be `person.maintenances`. The object `Person` does not have a class method `maintenances`. You should do this in two queries. One will return an array of `Maintenance` objects and the other returns an array of `Ability` objects. If you concatenate them (which is possible after two queries) the code that consumes the result will have to distinguish between different objects (Maintenance and Ability), unless they have some common methods.

Answer (score 0):

A simple join should do the trick:

```
Person.joins(:maintenance).where(maintenances: {status: 0, example: "yes"}).joins(:ability).where(abilities: {........})
```

Or something like this, which should create the same result

```
Person.where(maintenances: Maintenance.where(person: self, ......), abilities: Ability.where(person: self, ......))
```